# VBA Excel - How to call Form_Load event

Tags: vba, office365

I have a form that is being called from a menu button, and it loads fines, but I need to do some initialization when the form loads.  In .NET you would do something like:

```
Form1.Load Handles Me.Load
```

And when I click on the form, it generates a click event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    MsgBox ("Click")
End Sub
```

And when I click on the form the message box appears.  So far so good.

But I can't get the form load event to fire.

I tried UserForm_Open, UserForm_Load etc.  Nothing

For example this does nothing.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Open()
    MsgBox ("Open")
End Sub
```

Do I need to register the event somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this out

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
MsgBox ("Open")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had forgotten the old old way of adding the events, in the code window at the top, there are two drop downs, the left is for the control, the right is for the event.  select UserForm on the left and Initialize on the Right.